# Add second search condition Json API Python

Tags: python, api

I want to add a condition whereby you can search by calories in different ranges as well as search by ingredient inputted. i.e. to be able to return chicken and under 3000 calories. This is as far as I got, but unsure how to add it into the search.
 As a bonus I would also be able to work it out to be calories per serving rather than vs. calories for total meal.

CODE:

```
import requests


def recipe_search(ingredient):
recipes_appid = '0f89098e'
recipes_appkey = '80a8b7c8361daa22182bc3b3eb9f277e'
url = 'https://api.edamam.com/search?q={}&app_id={}&app_key={}'.format(ingredient, recipes_appid, recipes_appkey)
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

return (data['hits'])


def run():
ingredient = input('What ingredient is used by date first?')

calories = input('Do you want a low calories meal? Y/N').lower()

if calories =='Y':
    calorie_meal <= 3000
else:
    calorie_meal >= 3000

results = recipe_search(ingredient)



for result in results:
    recipe = result['recipe']

    print(recipe['label'])
    print(recipe['url'])
    print()


run()
```

Comment: ```if calories =='Y':
    calorie_meal <= 3000```, what is this supposed to do?

Comment: I am trying to ask the user if they want a low/medium/high calorie meal, then search based on that condition.

Comment: I am trying to ask the user if they want a low/medium/high calorie meal, then search based on that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [API reference](https://developer.edamam.com/edamam-docs-recipe-api), you can specify calories

> The format is calories=RANGE where RANGE is replaced by the value in kcal. RANGE is in one of MIN+, MIN-MAX or MAX, where MIN and MAX are non-negative integer numbers. The + symbol needs to be properly encoded. Examples: “calories=100-300” will return all recipes with which have between 100 and 300 kcal per serving.

So, add something like `calories='lower_bound-upper_bound'` to the query parameters.

Comment: Something like this? How to I add it as an actual search criteria to the search function?

    calories = input('Do you have a desired estimated calorie intake per meal?')


        lower_bound = 100
        upper_bound = 300

        if int(calories) < lower_bound:
            search

        elif int(calories) > upper_bound:
            search:
            
   else: search: 


    results = recipe_search(ingredient)


    for result in results:
        recipe = result['recipe']
        print(recipe['label'])
        print(recipe['calories'])
        print()


run()

Comment: Add it to `url` like you did with the other parameters, e.g. `&calories={}`.